# can you provide a working jsfiddle for popovers in bootstrap v4 or tell me what's wrong with this one?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you provide a working jsfiddle for popovers in bootstrap v4 or tell me what's wrong with this one? I found this working jsfiddle in bootstrap v3:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/svgx7r21/5/

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

I created a new jsfiddle and updated the v3 js/css refs to v4 and added the additional js libs requested by the console:

https://jsfiddle.net/random512/2jnL1u5a/2/

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

The console returns no errors but the jsfiddle doesn't work.  Any idea what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't use the same structure as Bootstrap 3. If you remove `display:none` from your popover rules then they will appear on click, you should also add the class of `popover` to your templates outermost div.

See [Options](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/#options):

> The outermost wrapper element should have the `.popover` class.

You'll have to rewrite your CSS with regards to the popover's arrow. Just inspect the element to see the changes.

**Minimal Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
})
```

```css
.example-class1 {
  background-color: #2a4254;
  height: 77px;
  width: 77px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.popover.popover1 {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0px 1px 1px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: #2a4254 !important;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: white;
}
.popover.popover1.bs-tether-element-attached-right::after,
.popover.popover1.popover-left::after {
  border-left-color: #2a4254;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="text-center example-class1" data-container="body" data-placement="left" data-content="This is a test" data-template='<div class="popover popover1" role="popover"><div class="popover-arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>' data-toggle="popover">Test 1</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```